# How to send multiple required headers for authentication in Custom GPT Actions

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to connect my Custom GPT to an external API (Klaviyo API), but the API requires 2 strings to be sent for authentication.

One is "Authorization", which it sent no problems with the Action, but the other requirement in the header is "Revision" with a date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

I can't seem to get the Action to send the required "Revision" information in the header, no matter what I try.

Is there a solution to this yet?

Here's the best spec code I have so far:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Klaviyo List Creation API
  description: API for creating a new list in Klaviyo with a specific REVISION header.
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://a.klaviyo.com/api
    description: Klaviyo API server
paths:
  /lists:
    post:
      operationId: createNewList
      summary: Create a new list in Klaviyo
      description: This endpoint creates a new list in Klaviyo.
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                data:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    type:
                      type: string
                      example: 'list'
                    attributes:
                      type: object
                      properties:
                        name:
                          type: string
                          example: 'Test List'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successfully created a new list
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  list_id:
                    type: string
                  name:
                    type: string
                  created:
                    type: string
                  updated:
                    type: string
      headers:
        Authorization:
          description: Klaviyo API Key
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            example: 'Klaviyo-API-Key your-api-key-here'
        Content-Type:
          description: Content type header
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            example: 'application/json'
        Accept:
          description: Accept header
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            example: 'application/json'
        Revision:
          description: API revision date
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            default: '2023-02-22'
```